# Approximate time taken by Boost Thread Specific pointer get() method

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, performance, thread-local-storage

We are using boost thread specific pointer to store some global data for that particular thread only. Below is the singleton we return when someone calls GetInstance().

My question is approximately how long it takes to get thread specific pointer (m_tspConnectionManager.get();) compared to normal pointer access?

I used the below code (where I call .get() method twice) and it took around 3 seconds to go through the complete function.

```
  typedef boost::thread_specific_ptr<ConnectionManager> ConnMgrPtr;
    static ConnMgrPtr m_tspConnectionManager;
    static ConnectionManager* GetInstance()
            {
                if(!m_tspConnectionManager.get())
                {
                    //first time called by this thread
                    //ConnectionManager* to be used in all subsequent calls from this thread
                    m_tspConnectionManager.reset(new ConnectionManager());
                }
                return m_tspConnectionManager.get();
            }
```

Now, I changed the above code to call .get() method only once and it took around 1.9 seconds.

```
    static ConnectionManager* GetInstance()
            {
                ConnectionManager* pConnMgr = m_tspConnectionManager.get();
                if(pConnMgr == NULL)
                {
                    //first time called by this thread
                    //ConnectionManager* to be used in all subsequent calls from this thread
                    m_tspConnectionManager.reset(new ConnectionManager());
                }
                return pConnMgr != NULL ? pConnMgr : m_tspConnectionManager.get();
            }
```

so, just by not calling .get() method I could see performance gain of 1.1 second. I have been trying to understand how we get the gain?
**note:** This gain might be the collective gain of calling GetInstance() function many times. Just trying to understand a single call gain here.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that thread_specific_ptr::get() is taking 1.1 seconds to execute. Even in debug mode. How are you timing these things?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify properly but 1.1 second is collective gain i.e. calling function many times. I just want to understand approximate single call gain.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that `get()` is taking much time (though, of course, it's slower than NOT calling `get()`.) With the "normal" implementation of TLS, your object is, at most, three pointer indirections away. (Thread block register -> TLS block -> your pointer.) But if you're calling `GetInstance()` enough, then any slowdown can become a big slowdown.

I'd look at how often `GetInstance()` is being called. Try to reduce that number by caching the returned pointer. Of course, the second implementation is preferable to the first.